# How to apply a filter to my pivot chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am trying to write a macro to create a pivot chart. I need the pivot chart to be a bar chart that has the columns filtered to only show 3 of the columns. Here is the code I have so far.

```
'Define Data Range
LastRow = Dsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Dsheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = Dsheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Studies Impacted")

'Insert Column Fields
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Studies Impacted").PivotFields("Study")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Studies Impacted").PivotFields("Workstream")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Studies Impacted").PivotFields("Study")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Name = "Status Count"
End With


'Format Pivot
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Studies Impacted").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Studies Impacted").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
```

I have tried using >add FilterType but it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried defining it as a PivotField but again, no results.

The result I want is a bar chart with only 3 of the studies being shown for each workstream. Instead, I am getting all of the studies.

Comment: does this help?

Comment: This is what I have come up with so far. I'm not sure which filter type to use. Would I use xlValueEquals? This doesn't seem right for a string variable. Please let me know what you think and where to add this part. ' With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Studies Impacted").PivotFields("Study")
        .ActiveFilters.Add2
    End With   '

Comment: updated my answer, I made mistake

Comment: the updated version works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your pivot chart and table are coupled.

You can filter up to two items using the method

```
pvtField.ActiveFilters.Add2
```

(excel 2013 or later)
or

```
pvtField.ActiveFilters.Add
```

(earlier than excel 2013)

You would run code like this

```
Sub main()
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim pvtFields As PivotFields
Dim pvtField As PivotField
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables(1)
pvtTable.AllowMultipleFilters = True

Set pvtFields = pvtTable.PivotFields
Set pvtField = pvtFields.Item(1)
pvtField.PivotFilters.Add2 xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="A", Value2:="B"
End Sub
```

Otherwise you must loop through the Pivot Items of the row that you are filtering

**CODE:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim pvtItems As PivotItems
Dim pvtItem As PivotItem
Dim Index As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set pvtTable = ws.PivotTables(1)
Set pvtItems = pvtTable.PivotFields(1).PivotItems

For Index = 1 To pvtItems.Count
    Set pvtItem = pvtItems.Item(Index)
    If pvtItem.Value = "A" Or pvtItem.Value = "B" Then
        pvtItem.Visible = False
    End If
Next Index
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]